# How can I create a prefab variant in C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying out Unity's new prefab workflow. I want to programmatically create prefab variant(s) on an prefab I've already created. I am using Unity 2018.3.0b7. How can this be done?

Comment: Don't just ask "how can this be done". ask more specific questions and post code examples of things you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

The `PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset` function is used to create a prefab variant. Note that you can only create prefabs and prefab variants in the Editor not in a build. To create a prefab variant, you first have to instantiate the prefab with `PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab` then you can use the `PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset` function to create the variant.

Load your prefab from file or get reference to your original prefab:

```
GameObject prefabRef 
 = (GameObject)AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath("Assets/Prefabs/YourPrefabName.prefab");
```

Instantiate the prefab the Editor way

```
GameObject instanceRoot = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefabRef);
```

Create prefab variant

```
GameObject pVariant = PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(instanceRoot, "Assets/Prefabs/PrefabOutputName.prefab");
```

Clean up the instantiated object

```
GameObject.DestroyImmediate(instanceRoot);
```

Note:

You need *Unity 2018.3b* and above to create prefab variant.